# How to call other scripts to run in gatling in a script?

Tags: java, gatling

Please tell me how to trigger the execution of two gatling scripts (I use java syntax) in the third.
I have script_1 and script_2, which are located in the simulations folder in gatling. I want to create a third script, script_3.java, so that in it I can initiate the simultaneous execution of those two scripts. Please tell me how this can be done?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you check out ChainBuilder() ?